# Add or remove one or more classes in chronoforms

Tags: php

Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument in chronoforms Extensions ?

Comment: like a http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/